# Replace CA Endevor with open source SCM tools like SVN/GIT or something else

Tags: git, svn, version-control, open-source, endevor

i have to write a paper about replacing Endevor with open source tools. My professor explained me Endevor as a source code management tool where i could create 3 stages for example:

> First stage for programmers for developing and testing their code. Then the code is beeing moved to the second stage where the QA test the source code for problems with automated tests. As final step the code is beeing moved to the production stage where it is used for releases and something like that.

Does someone know if and how a use case like that could be mapped with subversion, git or other tools? Creating stages, moving code from stage to stage and so on.

Comment: The question is a bit vague and overbroad. Read up on how Endevor works, and how other SCM work, and try to map Endevor's concepts. Then, if you come up with a concrete problem, edit your question to ask about that. As it stands, the question will likely get closed.

Comment: I did some research and i think that it is possible to create 3 directories and see them as 3 stages und copy sources from one directory to another. Am i right?

Answer (score 5):

Clarification: "Replace Endevor with **existing** open source tools"
This is required because generally if you want to replace an existing Endevor install you replace it with another COTS tool or with an inhouse bespoke application.

Let's go with the 'replace Endevor with existing open source tools' as see how far we can get.

It may be possible to replace Endevor with existing open source tools. Let's get a few points covered first though. The CA Endevor SCM software runs on the mainframe while open source tools generally run on midrange. This is much like saying that the software is running on Linux and you have Windows. This is a good simile as the mainframe has linux services and users in enterprise environments generally run Windows.

Endevor controls source code and the objects produced by source code generation. So we are talking about controlling source and various outputs which includes binary executable objects that are related to the code. These objects are generally stored on the mainframe file system. Each type of object is stored in an appropriate file container. Each environment stage has a set of these folders plus folders for the base and delta objects.

Endevor functions include retrieve, check out, check in, add, update, delete, transfer, sign out, sign in, package, move. Endevor allows for stages within an environment to be security controlled. Endevor configuration allows for multiple systems to be defined per stage; to handle multiple file types and allow for multiple options per type for processing (named processor groups within Endevor). An audit trail is cut to logs for any action.

The key functions here are the standard source control functions, element generation which includes program compiling, packaging, and release functions. The Endevor system calls mainframe programs to perform element generation - which includes the cobol compiler [IGYCRCTL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zappldev/zappldev_115.htm) and the CICS translator [DFHECP1$](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.doc/dfhs3/topics/dfhs3c001305.html) - to produce code that can be executed on the mainframe. In several cases, such as REXX and SAS programs, no modification may be required and the output is just a text file - although in some cases environment variable substitution occurs.

In order to run these programs you still need to store the result of element generation to mainframe libraries.
While your open source solution can store the source and store the binaries and other objects produced the code runs on the mainframe.

There is an assumption here that the end result of this is that the binary executables and other code objects arrive in the destination environments in the same controlled manner for which Endevor provides.

It is possible to access mainframe datasets from midrange.
It is possible to secure mainframe datasets so that only specific system userids can write to them and anyone can read them. See [RACF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Access_Control_Facility) or [ACF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACF2). 
It is possible to compile cobol and mimic the inheritance of mainframe libraries from midrange.
So, yes, It is possible to replicate Endevor functions using existing source control tools.

In addition, the mainframe has a linux side, omvs, for which can run possibly run the open source tools.

However, there are shortcuts. [Serena software](http://www.serena.com/) offers this functionality via its SCM suite, same for [IBM RDz](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/developerforsystemz/). If you really wanted 'free' software there is always IBM's [SCLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Software_Configuration_and_Library_Manager) (you get what you pay for).

Most of the time when a company who has or needs Endevor does not get it then they either get a competing product or code their own on the mainframe using mainframe tools - ISPF and REXX.

Endevor has both source control (SCM) and release management (DSL) for which covers multiple envrironments (DEV TEST and PROD) so you would need to be able to cater for the scenario where source objects and binary objects are delivered to a target environment.

If you do come up with a coherent answer please post it back here. You never know... someone may try to implement it one day.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about CA Endevor, but your descriptions sounds a bit like [git distributed workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) where an integration manager merge changes to different repositories.

Comment: It's still going to be running on the midrange side, and still going to be a PITA to implement and administrate. They could always try to get Gitlab or Github or something similar working on the mainframe itself.